# bash4: cp command cannot see files when enclosing file path inside a double quote

Tags: bash, quoting, cp

consider the following terminal output (inside a .sh file)

```
kagura@mylaptop1 : ~
=> sudo cp -a "$_source/*.txt" $_destination/Other/
Password:
cp: /home/myuser/*.txt: No such file or directory
08:06:13 Thu Jun 14
kagura@mylaptop1 : ~
=> sudo cp -a $_source/*.txt $_destination/Other/
08:06:33 Thu Jun 14
kagura@mylaptop1 : ~
```

The one with double quotes fails while the one without successfully runs.

I had the impression that double quoting when it comes to path/files is safe in the possibility that the path or file has a space.

Thanks for the help

Comment: [3.1.2.3 Double Quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Double-Quotes)

Answer (score 7):

`*` expands to the filenames in the folder, while `"*"` does not expand.

But your "impression" is right, you should quote all parts from which you are not 100% sure that there is no space in it.

You can mix quoted and non-quoted parts:

```
sudo cp -a "$_source"/*.txt "$_destination"/Other/
```

Comment: Also note, if `*.txt` expands to include files with spaces, this will not cause any problems for `cp`: the shell has performed word splitting before filename expansion, and it will not do a 2nd round of word splitting after the pattern is expanded. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions